# Querying a REST API with a string parameter using Angular Resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am trying to query a REST API which I have hosted locally and this should work something as follows:

```
http://localhost:51608/api/UserRole?email=john@example.com
```

That request works and it returns a User Object with an AccessLevel property. Now I have an angular application and want to query that URL using Angular Resource. I have something as follows but the URL is not being built properly.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("userRoleResource",
                ["$resource",
                 "appSettings",
                    userRoleResource])

    function userRoleResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/UserRole:email", { email: '@email'});
    }
})();
```

I am querying the above as follows:

```
userRoleResource.query({ email: vm.userData.email },
   function (data) {
      vm.userData.accessLevel = data.AccessLevel;
});
```

But this is generating the request as follows:

http://localhost:51608/api/UserRolejohn@example.com instead of http://localhost:51608/api/UserRole?email:john@example.com

What's wrong here?

Comment: function userRoleResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/UserRole?email=:email", { email: '@email'});
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `$resource` current working it does replace `:email` with the email parameter you provided to `$resource` object. You can have encoded `:` in a place like `%3A`

```
function userRoleResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/UserRole%3A:email", { email: '@email'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just format your string like :

```
return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/UserRole?email:" + email});
```

Comment: Are you considering to create `$resource` object each time when you call method? I don't think so that would be an good idea to go..